# How to extract document properties of .docx,.xlsx,.pptx using StgOpenStorageEx() function?

Tags: c++, windows, file-properties, compound-file

I am using **StgOpenStorageEx**() to get document properties like **Title,Subject,Tag,Authors**,etc..

I am successfully getting all these properties of .doc,.xls,.ppt files. But Not getting anything for **.docx,.xlsx,.pptx**

StgOpenStorageEx() is successfully opened for .docx file but not getting any properties.Why?

Anything am I missing?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

// Dumps simple PROPVARIANT values.
void DumpPropVariant(PROPVARIANT* pPropVar) {
    // Don't iterate arrays, just inform as an array.
    if (pPropVar->vt & VT_ARRAY) {
        printf("(Array)\n");
        return;
    }
    // Don't handle byref for simplicity, just inform byref.
    if (pPropVar->vt & VT_BYREF) {
        printf("(ByRef)\n");
        return;
    }

    // Switch types.
    switch (pPropVar->vt) {
    case VT_EMPTY:
        printf("(VT_EMPTY)\n");
        break;
    case VT_NULL:
        printf("(VT_NULL)\n");
        break;
    case VT_BLOB:
        printf("(VT_BLOB)\n");
        break;
    case VT_BOOL:
        printf("%s (VT_BOOL)\n",
            pPropVar->boolVal ? "TRUE/YES" : "FALSE/NO");
        break;
    case VT_I2: // 2-byte signed int.
        printf("%d (VT_I2)\n", (int)pPropVar->iVal);
        break;
    case VT_I4: // 4-byte signed int.
        printf("%d (VT_I4)\n", (int)pPropVar->lVal);
        break;
    case VT_R4: // 4-byte real.
        printf("%.2lf (VT_R4)\n", (double)pPropVar->fltVal);
        break;
    case VT_R8: // 8-byte real.
        printf("%.2lf (VT_R8)\n", (double)pPropVar->dblVal);
        break;
    case VT_BSTR: // OLE Automation string.
    {
        // Translate into ASCII.
        char dbcs[1024];
        char* pbstr = (char*)pPropVar->bstrVal;
        int i = wcstombs(
            dbcs, pPropVar->bstrVal, *((DWORD*)(pbstr - 4)));
        dbcs[i] = 0;
        printf("%s (VT_BSTR)\n", dbcs);
    }
    break;
    case VT_LPSTR: // Null-terminated string.
    {
        printf("%s (VT_LPSTR)\n", pPropVar->pszVal);
    }
    break;
    case VT_FILETIME:
    {
        const char* dayPre[] =
        { "Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat" };

        FILETIME lft;
        FileTimeToLocalFileTime(&pPropVar->filetime, &lft);
        SYSTEMTIME lst;
        FileTimeToSystemTime(&lft, &lst);

        printf("%02d:%02d.%02d %s, %s %02d/%02d/%d (VT_FILETIME)\n",
            1 + (lst.wHour - 1) % 12, lst.wMinute, lst.wSecond,
            (lst.wHour >= 12) ? "pm" : "am",
            dayPre[lst.wDayOfWeek % 7],
            lst.wMonth, lst.wDay, lst.wYear);
    }
    break;
    case VT_CF: // Clipboard format.
        printf("(Clipboard format)\n");

        break;
    default: // Unhandled type, consult wtypes.h's VARENUM structure.
        printf("(Unhandled type: 0x%08lx)\n", pPropVar->vt);
        break;
    }
}

// Dump's built-in properties of a property storage.
void DumpBuiltInProps(IPropertySetStorage* pPropSetStg) {
    printf("\n==================================================\n");
    printf("BuiltInProperties Properties...\n");
    printf("==================================================\n");

    IPropertyStorage* pPropStg = NULL;
    HRESULT hr;

    // Open summary information, getting an IpropertyStorage.
    hr = pPropSetStg->Open(FMTID_SummaryInformation,
        STGM_READ | STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE, &pPropStg);
    //hr = pPropSetStg->Open(FMTID_UserDefinedProperties,
       //STGM_READ | STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE, &pPropStg);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        printf("No Summary-Information.\n");
        return;
    }
    // Array of PIDSI's you are interested in.
    struct pidsiStruct {
        const char* name;
        long pidsi;
    } pidsiArr[] = {
       {"Title",            PIDSI_TITLE}, // VT_LPSTR
       {"Subject",          PIDSI_SUBJECT}, // ...
       {"Author",           PIDSI_AUTHOR},
       {"Keywords",         PIDSI_KEYWORDS},
       {"Comments",         PIDSI_COMMENTS},
       {"Template",         PIDSI_TEMPLATE},
       {"LastAuthor",       PIDSI_LASTAUTHOR},
       {"Revision Number",  PIDSI_REVNUMBER},
       {"Edit Time",        PIDSI_EDITTIME}, // VT_FILENAME (UTC)
       {"Last printed",     PIDSI_LASTPRINTED}, // ...
       {"Created",          PIDSI_CREATE_DTM},
       {"Last Saved",       PIDSI_LASTSAVE_DTM},
       {"Page Count",       PIDSI_PAGECOUNT}, // VT_I4
       {"Word Count",       PIDSI_WORDCOUNT}, // ...
       {"Char Count",       PIDSI_CHARCOUNT},
       {"Thumpnail",        PIDSI_THUMBNAIL}, // VT_CF
       {"AppName",          PIDSI_APPNAME}, // VT_LPSTR
       {"Doc Security",     PIDSI_DOC_SECURITY}, // VT_I4
       {0, 0}
    };
    // Count elements in pidsiArr.
    int nPidsi = 0;
    for (nPidsi = 0; pidsiArr[nPidsi].name; nPidsi++);

    // Initialize PROPSPEC for the properties you want.
    PROPSPEC* pPropSpec = new PROPSPEC[nPidsi];
    PROPVARIANT* pPropVar = new PROPVARIANT[nPidsi];

    for (int i = 0; i < nPidsi; i++) {
        ZeroMemory(&pPropSpec[i], sizeof(PROPSPEC));
        pPropSpec[i].ulKind = PRSPEC_PROPID;
        pPropSpec[i].propid = pidsiArr[i].pidsi;
    }

    // Read properties.
    hr = pPropStg->ReadMultiple(nPidsi, pPropSpec, pPropVar);

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        printf("IPropertyStg::ReadMultiple() failed w/error %08lx\n",
            hr);
    }
    else {
        // Dump properties.
        for (int i = 0; i < nPidsi; i++) {
            printf("%16s: ", pidsiArr[i].name);
            DumpPropVariant(pPropVar + i);
        }
    }

    // De-allocate memory.
    delete[] pPropVar;
    delete[] pPropSpec;

    // Release obtained interface.
    pPropStg->Release();

}

// Dump's custom and built-in properties of a compound document.
void DumpProps(char* filename) {
    // Translate filename to Unicode.
    WCHAR wcFilename[1024];
    int i = mbstowcs(wcFilename, filename, strlen(filename));
    wcFilename[i] = 0;

    IStorage* pStorage = NULL;
    IPropertySetStorage* pPropSetStg = NULL;
    HRESULT hr;

    hr = StgOpenStorageEx(wcFilename,
        0x00400000L | STGM_READ | STGM_SHARE_DENY_NONE, // Here: 0x00400000L = STGM_DIRECT_SWMR (Direct Single Writer Multiple Reader)
        STGFMT_ANY,
        // STGFMT_STORAGE //Structured Storage property sets
        // STGFMT_FILE  //NTFS file system property sets
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        IID_IPropertySetStorage,//IID_IPropertySetStorage,IID_IStorage
        reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pPropSetStg));

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        if (hr == STG_E_FILENOTFOUND)
            printf("File not found.");
        else if (hr == STG_E_FILEALREADYEXISTS)
            printf("Not a compound file. ERROR: %08lx", hr);
        else
            printf("StgOpenStorage() failed w/error %08lx", hr);
        return;
    }

    // Dump properties.
    DumpBuiltInProps(pPropSetStg);

    // Release obtained interfaces.
    if(pPropSetStg)
        pPropSetStg->Release();

}

// Program entry-point.
void main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char filePath[] = "C://word1.docx"; // file
  
    // Pass filename to the subroutine.
    DumpProps(filePath);
}
```

Comment: `StgOpenStorageEx` is for use with Compound Files. The newer Office Open XML files don't use CFBs for storage. Those are really ZIP archives.

Comment: @IInspectable then how can we extract properties for this new XML based file?

Comment: Finally, I have found out how to find such properties for XML based file. Thank you.